# Prove linear transformation has 5 distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $ T : \mathbb{R}^5\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5 $ be a normal linear transformation. There exists $ v \in \mathbb{R}^5 $ such that $ B= \left\{v, Tv, T^2v, T^3v, T^4v\right\} $ is linearly independent. I need to prove that $ T $ has 5 distinct eigenvalues.

Here is what I've tried so far:

$ \left|B\right|=5 $ and therefore $ B $ is a basis for $ \mathbb{R}^5 $.

$ \left|\lambda I - [T]_B\right| = \begin{vmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\delta_1 \\ -1 & \lambda & 0 & 0 & -\delta_2 \\ 0 & -1 & \lambda & 0 & -\delta_3 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & \lambda & -\delta_4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & \lambda-\delta_5 \end{vmatrix}  = (\lambda-\delta_5)\cdot\lambda^4-\delta_4\cdot\lambda^3-\delta_3\cdot\lambda^2-\delta_2\cdot\lambda -\delta_1$.

I now want to show that this polynomial factors into real linear terms and it is also the minimal polynomial of $ T $.

Could you give me a $ \textbf{hint} $ on how to solve this question?

Comment: What does "normal" means in this context ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe $ TT^t = T^tT $

Comment: @talopl and this gives you additional conditions on the $\delta_k$, maybe with that you can solve it

Comment: @talopl Hint : can you prove the statement in the particular case where $T$ is diagonalizable ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I can try. Assuming $ T $ is diagonalizable, we know that its minimal polynomial factors into distinct linear terms over $ \mathbb{R} $. Suppose there exists a polynomial $ P(x) \neq 0 $  s.t. $ \deg P \leq 4 $ and $ P(T) $ = 0. Therefore, there exist $ a_0, \ldots, a_5 $, s.t. $ a_1T^4v + \ldots + a_1v + a_0 = 0 $. $ \det([T])=0 \Rightarrow a_0=0$. The set above is lin. ind. $\Rightarrow a_4 = \ldots = a_1=0$. Therefore, the degree of the minimal polynomial is at least $ 5 $, and therefore there are five distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @talop Why is $\det([T])=0$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You're right, I miscalculated the determinant

Comment: There is a linguisitic problem: e.g. let $T$ be the cyclic shift operator (i.e. Companion Matrix for $x^n-1$, where $n=5$).  It is a permutation matrix, select $v:=\mathbf e_1$ and $B$ has 5 linearly independent vectors but only 1 *real* eigenvalue... inference: you are in effect being asked to work over $\mathbb C$. Anyway, if the minimal polynomial has degree $d\leq 4$ then $\left\{I, T, T^2, T^3, T^4\right\}$ is linearly dependent so $\left\{v, Tv, T^2v, T^3v, T^4v\right\}$ is as well.